# Why when dump a layer to memory, initial record is 1, if in original layer was 0?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, memory, standalone

I load a layer from a Shapefile (featuresA) and duplicate its contents into a memory layer (featuresB).

`featuresA[0].id()` is 0, but when copy his content to memory over featureB is 1,
`featuresB[0].id()` is 1.
Is that normal?

The following code is a  working example (standalone pyqgis script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from qgis.core import *

layerA = QgsVectorLayer("shapes01.shp", "shapes", "ogr")

#Populate layer A    
featuresA = [feat for feat in layerA.getFeatures()]

print "first id :"+str(featuresA[0].id())  # Print 0


# Duplicate layerA to layerB but into memory
layerB = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:4326&index=yes", "LayerB", "memory")
attr = layerA.dataProvider().fields().toList()
layerB_data = layerB.dataProvider()
layerB_data.addAttributes(attr)
layerB.updateFields()
layerB_data.addFeatures(featuresA)
layerB.updateExtents()

# Populate layerB        
featuresB = [feat for feat in layerB.getFeatures()]   

print "first id :"+str(featuresB[0].id())  # ¡¡¡¡ Print 1 ¡¡¡¡¡
```

The code works fine and all features are copied. I would expect that the ids of the features on the two layers match, which apparently is not the case.

Why does `featuresA[0].id()` (from file) give me **0** and `featuresB[0].id()` (layer duplicated into memory) give me **1**?

Comment: 42 is the answer to life the universe and everything. But, what is the  question? Apologies, I missed the fact that the question was entirely in the title. OK, without knowing the contents of featureA and featureB that is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: Ok, I restate the question.

Comment: It does not matter the content of the features. The source shapefile file can be any one containing Linestrings. The problem is with the id() that return 1 and must return 0, I think.  I try with diferents source shapefiles (only must content Linestrings (not poligons, not points)) and always return 1 for the feature[0].id() from memory layer.

Comment: Different data sources start with a different initial record number. This is a non-issue from the respect that the rowid column should not ever be relied upon for any user purpose.

Comment: Yes, different data sources could be start with different initial record, but in this example are the same source, featuresB is a copy of featuresA (but into memory, I don't understand why featuresA begin at 0 and featuresB begin at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature ids are used to unambiguously identify a feature on a particular layer. Ids are assigned by QGIS when a feature is retrieved the first time from a particular layer.

The important part of this is, that it is the *layer* (or more precisely, positive ones are from the data provider, negative ones from the layer) that assigns the id. It is not possible for you to give a feature and id and tell the layer to use this id. Nor is it possible to take a feature (with an id) from one layer and add it to another layer.

Many data providers have a counter to assign feature ids. But there is no standard that requires them to do so. They might also just spit out random numbers. The only thing a provider is required to do is to not hand out the same id twice and always hand out the same id for the same feature (or [emit a dataChanged() signal](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataProvider.html#a3ef3fe56a79c3a56fccb2cbb528aa886) before doing something different to these rules).

To explain this behavior: what would you think should happen if you add features from two different layers to a new memory layer? How should the memory layer deal with two features with the same id from different layers?

**What can feature ids be used for**

- They can be used to store a reference to a feature for retrieving the same feature later on during the same QGIS session and for the same layer.

**What can feature ids NOT be used for**

- Never use feature ids to link features between different layers.
- Never store feature ids on disk. The next time you start QGIS the same feature might receive a new id. And a different feature might have received the old id.
- It is even possible that feature ids change during a single QGIS runtime. In this case, a layer's dataProvider will [emit the dataChanged](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataProvider.html#a3ef3fe56a79c3a56fccb2cbb528aa886) signal.

**What should you do**

Add a unique identifier attribute to your data (or find an existing one which you can use for this purpose). Use this attribute to identify your features. This will help you to avoid all potential pitfalls and is easy and safe to use.

**So the answer to the question "why do different providers start the feature id counter with different values?"**

... is simply that there is no requirement for a provider implementation to follow a particular way of assigning feature ids. They could as well both start at 0, at 1 or at 42.

Comment: Ok, so differents providers -> maybe different initial record. That is ¡¡¡ Thanks.  The solution (what I have do  also) use another unique field as key .  Thank you very much.